# http status code for an expired link?

Tags: http

guys which is the correct status code for a link that expires in a certain amount of time?

I have thought to send a 404 after the expiration but maybe there is a better http status to send.

Example of link:

`mysite/dir/062011/file.exe` (<- working only within 06-2011)

Thanks

Answer (score 95, accepted):

How about 410 "Gone"?
See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @mr_eclair if the resource if perishable and intended to expire there would be nothing to redirect to.

Comment: This! Thank you. Exactly what I needed for an API conditional response.

Answer (score 25):

```
410 Gone

The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding
address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent.
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for 410 Gone when trying to validate an expired verification code in C# Web API. I use REST API Tutorial for reference https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Verify email address
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="verificationCode">Verification Code for ownership of an email address</param>
    /// <returns>Verify Email Update Api Response</returns>
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{verificationCode}/verify-email-update")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(VerifyEmailChangeApiResponse))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> VerifyEmailUpdate(Guid verificationCode)
    {
        var response = await this.emailVerificationService
            .VerifyEmailUpdate(verificationCode)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        switch (response.Result)
        {
            case VerifyEmailUpdateApiResultType.Ok:
                return this.Ok(response);

            case VerifyEmailUpdateApiResultType.EmailAddressAlreadyVerified:
                return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, response);

            case VerifyEmailUpdateApiResultType.Expired:
                return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.Gone, response);

            case VerifyEmailUpdateApiResultType.UnknownProblem:
                return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
        }

        return this.Ok(response);
    }
```